# Out parameters in C

Tags: c, parameters, pass-by-reference, out-parameters

```
void swap(int &first, int &second){
    int temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;
}
```

```
int a=3,b=2;
swap(a,b);
```

The compiler complaints that `void swap(int &first, int &second)` has a syntax error. Why? Doesn't C support references?

Comment: XOR swaps and such belong to the IOCCC, not in actual code or as advice to beginners.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C doesn't support passing by reference. So you will need to use pointers to do what you are trying to achieve:

```
void swap(int *first, int *second){
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}


int a=3,b=2;
swap(&a,&b);
```

---

**I do *NOT* recommend this:** But I'll add it for completeness.

You can use a macro if your parameters have no side-effects.

```
#define swap(a,b){   \
    int _temp = (a); \
    (a) = _b;        \
    (b) = _temp;     \
}
```

Answer (score 27):

C doesn't support passing by reference; that's a C++ feature. You'll have to pass pointers instead.

```
void swap(int *first, int *second){
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}

int a=3,b=2;
swap(&a,&b);
```

Answer (score -3):

for integer swap you can use this method without a local variable:

```
int swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    *a -= *b;  
    *b += *a;  
    *a = *b - *a; 
}
```

Comment: Should be `void swap(int* a, int* b)` to avoid the `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` (never hurts to check `if (*a != *b)` before swapping...)

Comment: Please, oh please, do not use this. Aside from having an incorrect return type, and being harder to read than the kind with a temporary variable, it's slower on almost every architecture. The only thing a third variable costs is a temporary register.